# Function value is defined when using return console.log but not simple return statement

Tags: javascript

So I have a function that finds the missing number given upper and lower bounds and the function logic works fine as

```
const findMissingNumber = (arr, upperBound, lowerBound) => {
    arr = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    let correctArray = [lowerBound];
    for (let i = 1; i < upperBound; i++, lowerBound++) {
        if (lowerBound + 1 < upperBound)
            correctArray[i] = lowerBound + 1;
        else
            break
    }
    correctArray.push(upperBound);
    arr.forEach((o, i, a) => {
        if (a[i] !== correctArray[i])
            return console.log(correctArray[i])
    })
}
```

this does log to console the value of 8,but I if use `return correctArray[i]` with `console.log(findMissingNumber(arrayOfIntegers, 9, 3))` i get `undefined` , what is the cause of this?

Comment: If you want to log something to the console, just console.log, don't do return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.find` instead of `.forEach`. Change the `console.log` to `return true` and return the result of the find.

```
return arr.find((o, i, a) => {
        if (a[i] !== correctArray[i])
            return true;
    })
```

You cannot return an enclosing function from within a lambda. You need to resolve to a value within the original function and return it from there.

Alternatively, use a simple for of loop instead of forEach.

Comment: Maybe just `return a[i] !== correctArray[i]` would make more sense. Currently this works because you're returning the fasly value of `undefined` if the condition is false, but using `return a[i] !== correctArray[i]` would make that check more explicit

Comment: for some reason, this returns the answer+1?